# Rendering Child Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, render

I am using React Native and React Navigation to build a simple app.
I have got the basic structure working with stub state but I am having problem with changing state via callback and re-render.

In my screen, I have simple start button

```
`<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
   <TouchableOpacity 
     style={[myStyles.buttonStyle, { backgroundColor: color }]} 
     onPress={() => handlePress(button.title)}
   >
     <Text style={myStyles.textStyle}>{button.title}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>`
```

Problem:

After I update my parent Component state, my child component does not instantly render to match the state change. I understood React will re-render all child components when parent state is changed?

Instead, I have to move back to previous screen and navigate again to my button screen to see that the button's color and text has changed correctly.

I've read about requiring a componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) handler but I am not sure how to use it. I put a console.log('nextProps', nextProps) inside but it does not get fired.

From navigation perspective, the Root component is on index[0] and my button view is at index[3] so it's the 3rd screen from the root.

EDIT 1: Added Code

myButton screen:

```
export class TeamsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.game.name}: Select Team`,
    headerTintColor: 'white',  
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    headerVisible: true
  })

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log('nextProps', nextProps);
}

render() {
  const { navigate, setParams } = this.props.navigation;
  const { game, player, setGameState } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  const color = game.status === 'Start' ? 'green' : 'red';
  const index = game.indexOf(player);
  const status = game.status;
  console.log('index', index);
  console.log('status', status);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
      style={[myStyles.buttonStyle, { backgroundColor: color }]} 
      onPress={() => setGameState(index, status)}
      >
        <Text style={myStyles.textStyle}>{game.status}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigate('ChangeDriverScreen', { team, game })}
        title='Change Driver'
       />
    </View>
    <View style={{ marginTop: 40, marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>Teams</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ height: 250 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={player.teams}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigate('TeamSelectedStartScreen', { team: item })}
              title={item.name}
            />
          </View>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      />
    </View>
    <Image
      style={{ alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end', height: 75, width: 250, resizeMode: 'stretch'}}
      source={require('./images/icons/playerPlaceholder.png')}
    />
  </View>
)}}
```

Then the onPress function that is called back:

```
setGameState = (gameIndex, status) => {
  console.log('setGameState', gameIndex, status);
  console.log('gameStateBefore', this.state.game);
  const newGameState = this.state.game.map(t => {
    console.log(this.state.game.indexOf(t));
    if (this.state.game.indexOf(t) === gameIndex) {
      const newStatus = status === 'Start' ? 'Stop' : 'Start';
      t.status = newStatus; /*eslint no-param-reassign: "off"*/
      console.log('inside if', t.status);
      console.log('inside if game', t);
      return t;
    }
    return t;
  });

  console.log('new Game State', newGameState);

  this.setState(() => ({
    game: newGameState
  }));
}
```

So the setState method works (as re-navigating back to screen 3 shows the correct state but core question is how to get immediate re-render of screen 3 when setState is called from Screen 0.

Comment: Share some more code , the function which you are calling on button click.

Comment: Yes as @ParasWatts said, add the code for whole screen.

Comment: Updated with code examples

Comment: declare function in screen 3 and write setState{this is just to rerender the screen.} in it. At screen 0, when setState is called _ below it call this function declared at screen 3. and the screen will rerender